# Error installing matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib, and I tried several different ways:

- I tried pip intall and easy_install, 
  both give me the same error: vcvarsall.bat not found
- I tried downloading it to my file, 
  and run it manually, but it won't stop running and created thousands of temp files, 
  eventually stopped with an error message cannot create temp file

I do not have admin right to the machine I am working with, so I cannot download visual studio.

However, I do have numpy and scipy installed, and I did add a new path in my environment variables pointing to my Python 3.3 folder.

Comment: What is your operating system?  Sounds like it's Windows.  If so, did you try downloading and running an EXE installer from [this page](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html)?

Comment: Windows, and I tried downloading and running an EXE installer. At It won't stop running and create thousands of temp file before returning an error of unable to create temp file.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about not having admin rights.  I'm not sure it's possible to install matplotlib on a systemwide Python install without admin rights.  Did you somehow install numpy and scipy that way, or were they already installed (or installed by an admin)?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib

Comment: I used easy_install for numpy and scipy, I installed pip by copying the ile from someone else (not downloaded)

Comment: try [anaconda](http://repo.continuum.io/anaconda3/)

Comment: I am new to python, what is anaconda?